# Impossible-to-find bug in a program that equalizes wealth in a group (UVA 10137, "The Trip")

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, debugging

I wrote a solution for [this competitive programming problem](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/101/10137.pdf). It passed all the test cases, except it was off by one for the last case, and I can't figure out why. The problem can be stated like this: given how many pennies each person in a group has, how much money has to change hands so that everyone in the group will be within one penny of each other in wealth?

My program is simple. I modified it to just operate on an array of how many pennies everyone has:

```
def transfer(A):
    A.sort(key = lambda x:-x)
    extra = sum(A) % len(A)
    average = sum(A) // len(A)

    high = sum([abs(x - (average+1)) for x in A[:extra]])
    low = sum([abs(x - average) for x in A[extra:]])

    return (high+low)/2
```

The test case that it fails on is the following:

```
print(transfer([613, 944, 7845, 8908, 12312, 22378, 27877, 54757, 55476, 90707, 91289, 178189]))
```

My code says the answer is `240710`, while the "correct" answer is `240709`. Where is my bug?

Comment: I'm inclined to think you actually had an error somewhere in the dollars->pennies or pennies->dollars conversion due to floating-point rounding.

Comment: No, the test case is in terms of pennies, and the incorrect answer is also in terms of pennies. Thanks though :)

Comment: I think there is no bug and your code is correct

Comment: I agree with @samgak. You can actually tabulate the transfers needed to arrive at the target condition and prove by example that 240,709 is wrong. (At least for the numbers you posted; are you sure you have the right test case for that answer?)

Comment: @TedHopp Wow, I just wasted like two hours trying to find the bug, then. Yes, I am sure this is the correct test cast. The reason I assumed I was wrong is that if you google this problem, tons of people implement solutions (all using the same algorithm, different than mine) that pass the online judge, which means either they're all wrong or I'm right. I'm not sure how to rigorously prove 240,709 is wrong; maybe there's a more efficient way to do the transfers than I'm doing? If you have a proof, I would be very interested to see how you do it :)

Comment: By the way, the testcases can be found [here](https://www.udebug.com/UVa/10137)

Comment: The only issue is which people end up with one extra penny. For _n_ people and _k_ extra pennies, you can do an exhaustive search by simply assigning the extra pennies to each possible combination of _k_ people among the _n_. I believe (but haven't checked) that the only time the assignment makes a difference is if you **needlessly** assign an extra penny to someone who is already at or below the average or fail to assign an extra penny to someone who's above the average. As far as I can tell, your algorithm doesn't do that.

Comment: P.S. I haven't done that exhaustive search. I'd be very interested to see an assignment that results in 240,709 transfers instead of 240,710.

Comment: @TedHopp [Here](https://codingstrife.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/solution-uva10137-pc110103-the-trip/) is a solution+"proof" written by someone else that gets 240709 (they write it as $2407.09, see their C++ code). The people who run the online judge must have solved it according to this solution. Can you see what the problem is there?

Comment: @TedHopp I thought maybe float imprecision was the problem, since their solution uses floating point arithemtic on the dollar amounts. However, I replaced `double` with `long double` in their solution, which would have fixed that problem, and got the same answer. So the problem is with the algorithm: one of us is wrong.

Comment: `if (deficits[i] < surplus[i]) deficits[i] = surplus[i];` looks suspicious.  The two are equal in integer arithmetic

Comment: @stark Well I think that's there because they use a real-valued average, whereas I use a floored average. Also, like I said, my `long double` typedef should have eliminated any errors due to imprecision, right?

Comment: I ran the linked solution on `12 6.13 9.44 78.45 89.08 123.12 223.78 278.77 547.57 554.76 907.07 912.89 1781.89 0` and got `$2407.10`. (This is with clang 8 on macOS Sierra.)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Wow, that is *weird*, because `g++` on ubuntu gives `$2407.09`. So it must be some weird floating point bug; the algorithm is at least correct. That's *weird*!!!!!! And gcc gives a different result, too! Wow! ... Do you have any idea why `long double` wouldn't have taken care of it?

Comment: Here are my compiler specs: http://pastebin.com/9wPYg0cT

Comment: I get the same result with GCC 6, so probably a standard library thing.

Comment: Excel says 240710. Why solve it in Python when you have Excel? Excel is used by managers - it cannot be wrong ;-)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Hm. Thats really weird and concerning, because they should both implement the same floating point arithmetic standards. Also, why wouldn't `long double` fix it? That doubles the bits of precision.

Comment: I think looking at roundoff error is a red herring. I have to think that the C++ "solution" is simply wrong. I haven't run it yet, but I find the "explanation" part of that post to be dubious. Your algorithm makes total sense--you're simply counting things.

Comment: @TedHopp If you google [the problem](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=10137+the+trip&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), you'll find lots of people who came up with the same explanation. I'm not sure that it's wrong (though it's certainly not stated well in my link). Only [one person](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=10137+the+trip&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) seems to have used my algorithm. I think the problem really is floating-point arithmetic, because clang and gcc disagree. Anyway, it's disappointing that the UVA Online Judge uses a flawed solution for this problem

Comment: @RenéG With the configuration where it does give you `$2407.09`, what are the exact input values it stores? You can print them with `for (int i=0; i<students; i++) printf("%.60f\n", payments[i]);`.

Comment: The 240710 is provably correct, let me know if you want a sketch. I also don't see how the linked alternate solution could possibly produce 240709.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consensus seems to be that the reason I got a different answer is that I use exclusively integer arithmetic, and their answer uses float arithmetic. While their algorithm would be correct in infinite precision, it turns out that in this case, by a weird fluke, float imprecision gives an off-by-one. This is verified by `gcc` compiling code that gives a different answer than mine, but `clang` compiling code that gives the same answer I found.

Answer (score -1):

The programming problem states:
    Your job is to compute, from a list of expenses, the minimum amount of
money that must change hands in order to equalize (within a cent) all the students’ costs.

That is not the same as everyone having the same wealth within a penny. It means that every exchange of money should be within a penny. Poor wording, with some degree of confusion over interpretability. But let's go with it.

There are five people who are above the average value of 45941.25. They are the people who are giving the money to the others. But when there's less than one penny to be given, they don't need to give that fractional cent. To find out how many people don't need to hand over an extra cent:

```
extra = len([x for x in A if x > sum(A)/len(A)])
```

`final = initial - difference`. By inspection, the `final` values are within the one penny criteria.

```
initial = [178189, 91289, 90707, 55476, 54757, 27877, 22378, 12312, 8908, 7845, 944, 613]
difference = [132247, 45347, 44765, 9534, 8815, -18064, -23563, -33629, -37033, -38096, -44997, -45328]
final = [45942, 45942, 45942, 45942, 45942, 45941, 45941, 45941, 45941, 45941, 45940, 45940]
```

The five people who have too much money give `[132247, 45347, 44765, 9534, 8815]` pennies away, giving away a total of `240708 cents`. It seems to square up nicely.

Note that it is a lower value than the solution given above!

Comment: Note that the "solution" is not actually correct. If you look at `final`,  two people with 45942 must give one penny to the two 45940's to even things out. By inspection, we can see that this solution I proposed is a bit fishy. But a real way to solve the problem would be to generate the correct values in final, then subtract them from the initial values.

Comment: If your add two to your answer you get my answer. And your above comment indicates that you have to add two to your answer. So I'm not sure I see how this is a counterexample.

Comment: Sorry Rene G, the counterexample is that I have shown (most of) the work needed to inspect "final". It is simple to see that the "within one penny" final = [45942, 45942, 45942, 45941, 45941, 45941, 45941, 45941, 45941, 45941, 45941, 45941] and then calculate the remainder.

Comment: To calculate both the positive and negative money transactions, then divide by 2, seems to be an inefficient way to do accounting. Use only the values in initial above the average, subtract from them the corresponding final values, and sum the result. That's the answer.